# how to using overflow-y visible with overflow-x scroll in div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I coding `overflow-y: visible` with `overflow-x: scroll`?

The number of buttons can vary and when there are too many of them, they scroll horizontally. If I clicked Dropdown button, then I want to make `overflow-y: visible` in `div`. But now, dropdown lists are hidden in `div`.

How do I change?

**My Code part**

**html**

```
  <div class="container-fluid fill-height">
      <div class="navbar navbar-expand scroll" role="group">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="testDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="testDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">BUTTON</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

[Codepen live sample here](https://codepen.io/ofleaf/pen/yxmJOg)

Comment: This is codepen. https://codepen.io/ofleaf/pen/yxmJOg

Comment: Where's your code part?

Comment: @core114 Can't you see my codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One last thing:

From the bootstrap official doc (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment):
May require additional positioning
Dropdowns are automatically positioned via CSS within the normal flow of the document. This means dropdowns may be cropped by parents with certain overflow properties or appear out of bounds of the viewport. Address these issues on your own as they arise.

```
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/411
https://www.bootply.com/YvePJTDzI0
```